# How can I migrate data and related data from one org to another org?

Tags: data-loader, migration-tool, data-migration

I have a requirement to migrate data and I have a lot of related data, records and relationships to maintain.

Is there a utility or tool to help me do this to minimize the amount of manual steps I would have to do to migrate data and related data from one org to another org?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide you can use force.com migration tool which uses ant for migration

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a few different tools out there on the AppExchange and elsewhere that allow you to upload related records in a single pass. Services like Sesame Software's Relational Junction, Informatica, and Dataloader.io can do this, and have varying costs depending on how much you want to migrate. Please do appropriate research before selecting a service; the named products are simply examples, not an endorsement for any particular service.

Migration using Salesforce DX is possible with its force:data:tree:export and force:data:tree:import commands, but works better with small batches (hundreds to thousands of records). However, there's no real GUI for it, so you have to do a bit of typing to get things done.

The Apex Data Loader doesn't do this out of the box, but with some work in Excel you could do this manually. I've successfully migrated a few hundreds of thousands of records in just a day or so manually, you just need to be aware of how to map the old ID values to the new ones; I typically use External ID fields to keep my records straight until I'm done.

Comment: Thanks. What i'm really asking is there a  utility to help handle the manual part of finding the relations or related data using excel?I mean we have tons to do.

Comment: @user58 Are you trying to discover the relationships on the object? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: On the Appexchange, both Data Migrator and Prodly Moover will maintain your data's relationships when you copy to the target instance.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes.That is correct. I want discover the relationships on the object.

Comment: @user58 Do you know about the Schema Browser? It's in Setup, and lets you see the relationships pretty easily.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have heard of it. Let try again I have data and other related data in org A .  I need to check and migrate the data and relationships from Org A match up  with the data and related data in Org B. We have a very complicated and tons of dependencies if  we don't bring over the right data that its expecting.

Comment: @user58 As sfdcfox mentioned in the answer, you just need to maintain an "external id" on the new records which will necessarily contain the ids of the old records being migrated, which will then help establish the relationship while using any of the tools.

Comment: Try https://sync.helpfulbits.com

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a sfdx plugin specifically on this matter.
Please checkout this github readme.
Its pretty straight forward -

[GitHub repo to the sfdx plugin](https://github.com/darkacer/generate-plan) - readme guides how to install the plugin

1. You specify a JSON file with queries in it.
2. Run the command with path to json file and the user to run the command against
3. It will generate plan for your queries in specified path
4. Use standard sfdx import command to import data to org of your choice using the plan files

Checkout this
demo video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpq2v_D3K7U)

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the following article (#000326326): [Best Practices when you migrate data](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000326326&type=1)

The main points:

> 1. Identify the data you want to migrate
> 2. Create templates for the data
> 3. Populate your templates
> 4. Prepare the destination org
> 5. Validate the data

Anyone can do complex data migration manually also, but if someone needs to do this frequently I highly suggest using the available data migration App Like: Prodly or  iSyncSF.

Answer (score -2):

You can avoid the time- and effort-consuming manual data migration. Let Salesforce partner transfer your business information from one org to another one accurate and safe saving all the relations between records.

Go to AppExchange and take a look at [Data2CRM](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EjVSuUAN).

Hope it will help.

*I manage the customer experience for Data2CRM*

Comment: Posting a link to a specific product under the title "AppExchange" is a bit deceptive. Please note that you [must disclose your affiliation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), if any.

Comment: I've edited the link. Guess the answer is relevant as the question is about a utility or tool to help migrate data and related data from one org to another org. Is it OK now?

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product? You certainly seem to be, since your only three answers are promotional. You're not complying with the spam policy I linked to.

Comment: This question does indeed disclose your affiliation appropriately. As such, I will clear the spam flag for now. But if everything you post is self promotional, you still may run afoul of our policies.

Comment: OK, thank you for the insight. I'll keep it in mind and follow the policies by posting useful answers, not the promotional only.